# Emacs how to run a command that requires a default editor remotely from with local Emacs?

Tags: tramp, ssh, remote

I frequently use TRAMP to edit files on a remote machine but I also want to use Emacs for remote configuration and management.

On any system there are some commands that run with the `VISUAL` and `EDITOR` variables which open local edits.

Usually there is a corresponding file that these programs edit but these files should not be edited directly as there is syntax checking that occurs after the files are edited.

So if I am using TRAMP from my local machine, and I run a command such as `crontab -e` on the remote machine (over `tramp-term` or `ansi-term`) it will open the default editor on the remote machine.

Frequently I am `ssh`'d in as my own user account, so this will often open a second instance of Emacs in my local Emacs' shell.

This is very bad for key command interception etc.

Is it possible to make the default editor for commands like `visudo` and `crontab` my *local* Emacs?